# What is a good proposal distribution for this density (in rejection sampling)? Is mine correct?

Tags: bayesian, self-study, monte-carlo, rejection-sampling

I have this density, I want to find a density "larger" than this

$f(x)=\frac{1}{c}g(x)(1-\sin (20x)/4))$
, where $g(x)$ is N(0,1).

I am looking for a proposal distribution for f(x), basically find a density that is "larger" everywhere than the one above?

I was told to use g(x), but g(x) is not always "larger" because of the sine function.  I was hinted to use g(x), possibly the answer.  But it just doesn't make sense to me.  Can someone give me a hint?  Thanks!

Comment: Hints: (1) exactly how large can $1 - \sin(20 x)/4$ ever get?  (2) Your approach shouldn't depend on $g$ being a Normal PDF; it should work for *any* PDF that varies sufficiently slowly.

Comment: (1) it 's between 1 and 2, probably somewhere 1.5 looking at my graph. (2)I agree with any pdf, but N(0,1) is the easiest, no?

Comment: To answer my own question, I need to multiply g(x) by a constant, say 2, now it will be uniformly larger. yes!

Comment: Hmm...because the sine has a range from $-1$ to $1$, you *ought* to find that the range of $1-\sin(20x)/4$ is from $1-1/4$ to $1+1/4$.  That should lead you to conclude that when you use an appropriate multipler the acceptance rate is around 80% (*exactly* 80% for any pdf symmetric about 0, like a Normal), which is pretty efficient.  With a multiplier of 2 the acceptance rate goes down to 50%: not bad, but still 63% worse than the best you can do.

Comment: ok, when I said 1.5, I was talking about the max, because that's what matters in the problem.

Comment: The max isn't 1.5.

Comment: right, it isn't, when I did my rejection sampling, it was giving me back 100 out of 100 samples.  Just curious, what is your idea on proposal distribution?  My take is that some kind of scaled g(x).